# Flutter - Unterminated string literal

Tags: json, flutter, http, dart

I am trying to use an `http post` method, however I get the error `Unterminated string literal` in my debug console, when I try to parse a Map inside a Map in my JSON method in `report_config`,

```
Future<Reports> request() async {
      final http.Response response = await http.post(
        'some_url',
        headers: <String, String>{
          'id': 'some_id',
          'auth_token': 'some_token'
        },
        body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
          'start_date': '2020-01-01', //Works fine
          'end_date': '2020-09-15', //Works fine
          'report_config': '{ //Here is where the error is
            "dimensions": {
              "devices": true,
              "country": true,
            },
            "metrics": {
              "total_impressions": true,
              "total_clicks": true,
            }
          }',
        }),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server is expecting a string for the `report_config` field, you should json encode it, like this:

```
'report_config': json.encode({
            "dimensions": {
              "devices": true,
              "country": true,
            }),
```

Answer (score 1):

In the line: `'{ //Here is where the error is`, remove the `'` and the corresponding one that shows up later.

Comment: I need the ' part because thats how the server wants me to make a request

Comment: @ArnavVaryani What do you mean? That's simply not valid dart.